# WooCommerce REST API - Filter Orders By Date Modified

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the WooCommerce REST API (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) and can download Customers, Orders, etc successfully.

I'm now trying to get a filtered list of Orders where the Date Modified for the Order is after a certain date, but haven't been able to get this to work so far. The response to get GET request for an Order includes:

```
"date_modified": "2016-12-21T00:33:38",
```

I've tried the following:

```
wp-json/wc/v1/orders?filter[modified]=2017-02-14
```

but that just returns all orders. I would like to change the = to be a >= so it gets all Orders after the specified date, but haven't been able to find an example of how to structure the request URL for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the following request format:

wc-api/v1/orders?filter[updated_at_min]=2017-02-22&filter[updated_at_max]=2017-02-25

Comment: That works for me in my testing wit the v2 REST API. You would also try something like this:

/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2017-05-17T00:00:00Z&before=2017-05-17T23:59:59Z

Comment: yes, the above used to work for orders, but this didn't work for customers. Also I think this is not a Woocommerce feature but a Wordpress one.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Tested with Woo 4.0.x / API v3

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query', function(array $args, \WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $modified_after = $request->get_param('modified_after');

    if (!$modified_after) {
        return $args;
    }

    $args['date_query'][0]['column'] = 'post_modified';
    $args['date_query'][0]['after']  = $modified_after;

    return $args;

}, 10, 2);
```

/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/?modified_after=2020-05-09T14:00:00

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: By using `woocommerce_rest_product_object_query`, this exact solution works for products also. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Worked for me, but returning only 10 results... with `&per_page=20` you can increase to 20... Note that the maximum is 100 results only ! :(

Comment: @Meloman. tryout this and see whether it'll work for you. This is for products update to orders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476534/get-all-products-from-woocommerce-using-rest-api/63187237#63187237

Answer (score 4):

As of WooCommerce 5.8 (released October 21, 2021), [Muhwezi Jerald Basasa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62977700/6275275) is no longer necessary.

The WooCommerce API now supports the modified_after and modified_before parameters for the `products`, `orders` and `coupons` endpoints.

More information:

- https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/10/12/woocommerce-5-8-released/
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/5.8/changelog.txt

Answer (score 2):

This is working:

```
/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2019-01-10T00:00:00Z&before=2019-01-10T23:59:59Z
```

Comment: this is for "date_created", but not "date_modified" date :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with the following steps:

1. Create a folder.
2. Create a file with the same name and the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   /**
    * Plugin Name: ModifyOrder
    */

   function modify_orders_after_query($request) {
       $request['date_query'][0]['column'] = 'post_modified';
       return $request;
   }

   add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query", 'modify_orders_after_query' );
   ```
3. Drop it in the wp-content/plugins folder.
4. In the admin panel, you can see your folder name as a plugin,
   activate it and try!

Answer (score 0):

It's Working

```
WooCommerce.get("products?after=2020-11-24T09:01:14&before=2020-11-25T04:51:22")
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the woocommerce API doesnt actually implement the filter. Its from wordpress api which is used with woocommerce and latest wordpress doesnt support filter anymore. For latest wordpress you must add the filter functionality manually by adding wordpress rest api filter provided by the wp-api team